# Service Oriented Architecture approach

Tags: service, architecture, soa

Is SOA solution by making a centralized service which works as a central backbone service for all other services is a good approach?

Comment: you could work in the detail of your question a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Its doable, but you need to consider service granularity.

Incorrect granularity could mean that a service covers too much functionality or too little functionality.

Incorrect granularity of services in your SOA can lead to bad performance, low reuse possibilities, leaky abstractions and services without added business value.

Other problems:

You're not able to explain to business people (e.g. sales/marketing) what the service does. It simply does not fit in their understanding of the business the company is in. The services are at a level of detail that is irrelevant from a business perspective.

Many different services are needed to achieve something of value to the business.

There is no clear ownership of the service, multiple department feel they should own the service (or parts of it).